# .axml file live previewer for Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

The preview for Xamarin's android development is in a word, unkind. It has to re render the view everytime and isn't as smooth as the Android studio one.

I keep hearing about XAML previewers. Why can't I preview my .axml files using these applications?

Comment: SO can't really answer a "WHY" question about the design of a commercial software package.  The XAML previewer is for Xamarin Forms, whereas the AXML is for Android Native UI.  Two different things managed by two different teams with different goals and priorities.  If you want to request enhancements to the AXML previewer, do it here: xamarin.uservoice.com

Comment: Personally I use Android Studio for my UI design/layout of `axml` when I need a WYSIWYG view and just toggle between it and Xamarin Studio.... There are even `.vsix` extensions so you can do this with Visual Studio and Android  Studio on Windows....

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I understand. Will suggest improvements to the Axml previewer to the team. And I will get Android Studio and use that for designing purposes. Thank you.

Comment: @SushiHangover Do you know the names of these addins?  Thanks.